# Creating users in Windows 2003

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003

I need a script to create 10 users in Windows 2003.

Comment: I'm glad to know that you need a script to create 10 users in Windows 2003 (suggested reading: http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Comment: sudo make me a sandwich.

Comment: Fortunately we can just post our wants on SO and the code monkeys will hop to.  Oh, wait.

Answer (score 2):

Will VB script work?

```
Option Explicit
Dim strUser
Dim objRootLDAP, objContainer, objNewUser

for count =0 to 9

strUser = "stackOUser" + count 


Set objRootLDAP = GetObject("LDAP://rootDSE")
Set objContainer = GetObject("LDAP://cn=Users," & _
objRootLDAP.Get("defaultNamingContext")) 

' Build the actual User.
Set objNewUser = objContainer.Create("User", "cn=" & strUser)
objNewUser.Put "sAMAccountName", strUser
objNewUser.SetInfo 

next

WScript.Quit
```